# Rename can't find sequence in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to rename a sequence in my Oracle SQL database (let's call it `OLD_SEQUENCE`). Per the [RENAME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9019.htm) documentation, I can use that command to rename a sequence:

> Use the `RENAME` statement to rename a table, view, sequence, or private synonym.

So using this documentation, I tried to create the following command:

```
RENAME old_sequence TO new_sequence
```

but unfortunately, that produced the following SQL error:

```
Error executing SQL RENAME old_sequence TO new_sequence: 
ORA-04043: object old_sequence does not exist
```

I confirmed that this is exactly how the sequence appears in the database, so I tried adding the owner

```
RENAME owner.old_sequence TO new_sequence
```

but that didn't work either

```
Error executing SQL RENAME owner.old_sequence TO new_sequence: 
ORA-01765: specifying owner's name of the table is not allowed
```

I find it strange that the error here was that it thought it was a table rather than a sequence.

I get the same result when I apply the owner name to both:

```
RENAME owner.old_sequence TO owner.new_sequence
```

So how can I solve this issue where rename can't find the sequence in Oracle SQL?

Comment: Are you the owner of the sequence?  Can you show the results of querying `user_sequences` to show the sequence name?  Is it possible that the old sequence was created as a case-sensitive identifier and you're not using a case-sensitive identifier in your `rename` command?

Comment: @JustinCave I am not the original owner, but access has been granted through the `GRANT` command. For what it's worth, I can `CREATE` new sequences and `ALTER` existing sequences under this owner as well. My rename uses an exact copy-paste of the table name, so case sensitivity shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Thunderforge where did you copy the sequence name from? What does `select sequence_name from all_sequences where lower(sequence_name) = 'old_sequence';` give you? If it's not all in capitals, then you will need to surround your name in double-quotes when you work with it, eg. `rename "old_sequence" to ...`

Comment: @Thunderforge also, you might find it helps to switch the current schema over to that of the schema that owns the sequence, e.g.: `alter session set current_schema=sequence_owner;` before attempting to run the rename. I'm not convinced this will work, but you never know! **Actually, scratch all that; [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general006.htm) says that you have to be the owner of the object in order to be able to rename it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation that you linked to:

> Prerequisites
>
> The object must be in your own schema.

So the fact that you are granted access to it is irrelevant. If you don't own it, you can't rename it.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to rename with specifing th new owner even its the same :

> RENAME owner.old_sequence TO new_owner.new_sequence

BTW it s normal to get the word "table " in the response it's just a message problem.

Comment: I did try adding it to both (the owner is the same). I added that to the question.